# Local global minimizers and maximizers

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to find the local and global minimizers and maximizers of the following two functions.
1) $f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$
2) $f(x)=x+ \sin x $

These are my answers.

> 1)  $f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$    $f'(x)=e^{-x^2} 2 x(1-x^2)$   Thus the
>   critical points are  $x=0,1,-1$   $f''(x)=e^{-x^2}(2-10x^2+4x^4)$
>   $f''(0)=2>0$.  Thus $x=0$ is a strict local minimizer of $f(x)$.    As
>   $f''(1)=f''(-1)=-4e^{-1}<0$, $x=1,x=-1$ are strict local maximizers of
>   f(x).   As $f(x)  -> 0 $ when $x->+\infty$ and  $x->-\infty$ ,
>   $x=1,x=-1 $are strict global minimizers.
>    Also since $e^{-x^2}>0$
>   and thus $f(x)>=0 ; \forall x \in R$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0, x=0 $ is
>   a strict global minimizer.

Is this correct?
For 2)

> $f(x)=x+ \sin x$   $f'(x)=1+\cos x$   Thus the critical points are
>   $x*=2n\pi \pm \pi$     $f''(x)=-\sin x$.   But f''(x*)=0.     So are
>   the critical points **inflection points**? **How can I show that they are inflection points?**
>   Also $f(x)  -
> > +\infty $ when $x->+\infty$ and $f(x)  -> -\infty $ when $x->-\infty$.

Therefore I conclude that there are no global maximizers and minimizers and there are no local maximizers and minimizers as well. Is this correct?

Comment: The sine function has its own symbol in $\LaTeX$, so if you prefix the `sin` with a backslash you'll get the function name in upright font instead of italics: `\sin x` renders as $\sin x$. Same applies to cosine, tangent etc.

Comment: The first answer is correct (and you expect the non-zero extrema to be in pairs, since the function has even symmetry).  The conclusion in the second problem is  also correct .  You have found the critical points correctly.  It _is_ possible to have local extrema with both the first _and_ second derivatives equal to zero (consider $ \ y \ = \ x^4 \ $) .  Does the sign of the concavity change "on either side" of the critical point?  If not, it is a local extremum; if it does change, then it is a point of inflection.  (The ones in the second function turn out to be inflection points.)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner   in part 2 how can I show that the sign of concavity change on either side of the critical  point

Comment: What is the sign of $ \ f''(x) \ $ for a value of $ \ x \ $ slightly less than, say, $ \ \pi \ $ compared to a value slightly larger than that?  Does this also hold for all the critical points you found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts 1 and 2 are correct as others have already pointed out.

Now, addressing your specific questions in Part 2:

*--Are the critical points in Part 2 inflection points? How can I show they are inflection points?*

You´ve shown that $x^*=2n\pi+\pi$, $n\in \Bbb Z$, are critical points, as $f'(x^*)=0$. But notice that, as $f'(x)=1+\cos x\ge 0$, $\forall x\in \Bbb R$, the function $f(x)$ is monotone non-decreasing, so the critical points you've found are indeed inflection points.